# How to see the internal content of an index?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, indexing

When creating an index on a column `value`:

```python
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);")
db.execute("CREATE INDEX data_idx ON data(value);")
for v in ["xyz", "abc", "def", "abc", "ijk"]:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO data(value) VALUES (?)", (v,))
```

**how to display the internal content of the index?** For learning purposes, and also in more complex cases, seeing what is stored exactly in the index would be helpful.

As `data_idx` is not a real table, this fails with `no such table: data_idx`:

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM data_idx")
```

How to display the internal content of a Sqlite index? (it should be a correspondance between sorted values and `rowid`s I guess?)

Comment: Maybe first reading the [SQLITE_MASTER](https://database.guide/list-indexes-in-sqlite-database/) to detect what fields are in your index, then compute a second query to gather the result ?

Comment: @tgrandje `"SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index';"` gives `('index', 'data_idx', 'data', 3, 'CREATE INDEX data_idx ON data(value)')`, but I'd like to see the internal content inside the index: the items should be sorted, and see the matching `rowid`s, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using https://sqlite.org/imposter.html, we can create an "imposter" table that shares the same data as the index. We can then display the content of this table, i.e. the content of the index.

**Warning (from the doc) :**

> Imposter tables are intended for analysis and debugging only. This is
> not a feature that most application developers should understand or
> even know about. Imposter tables are for experts only. Improper use of
> imposter tables can cause index corruption, though any corruption
> created this way can be fixed by running REINDEX.

```python
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('index.db')
db.executescript("""
CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT); 
CREATE INDEX data_idx ON data(value);
INSERT INTO data(value) VALUES('xyz'), 
                              ('abc'), 
                              ('def'),
                              ('abc'),
                              ('ijk');

PRAGMA writable_schema=ON;
INSERT INTO sqlite_master(type, name, tbl_name, rootpage, sql)
     VALUES('table', 'data_idx_2', 'data_idx_2', (SELECT rootpage FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='data_idx'),
            'CREATE TABLE data_idx_2(value, id, PRIMARY KEY(value, id)) WITHOUT ROWID')
""")
db.commit()
db.close()  # required to close / open, see documentation
db = sqlite3.connect('index.db')
for r in db.execute("SELECT * FROM data_idx_2"):
    print(r)
```

Then, this is the content of the index:

```
('abc', 2)
('abc', 4)
('def', 3)
('ijk', 5)
('xyz', 1)
```

Comment: Good idea! Feel free to edit the answer with this info @tgrandje!